# How to get a valid strings array in JSON format?

Tags: arrays, json, basic-authentication

I have and string array in json format as follows, which I will be adding to my API header

```
[\"Authorization:\ Basic\ T1BFTlZJRFVBUFA6UmVzcG9uc2VARXllITIz\"]
```

But I get the below error when I try to restart my server which has the above property set in .env file

> Property OPENVIDU_WEBHOOK_HEADERS=[\"Authorization:\ Basic
> T1BFTlZJRFVBUFA6UmVzcG9uc2VARXllITIz\"]. Is not a valid strings array
> in JSON format. com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException:
> Expected value at line 1 column 2 path $[0]

What would be the correct way to define the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to do with the escaping of your string.

Correct String :

```
["Authorization: \"Basic T1BFTlZJRFVBUFA6UmVzcG9uc2VARXllITIz\""]
```